# insert cart total as reward points in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

im trying to get the cart total from the checkout and once the users confirms the order, to add the total amount as reward points...

for an example lets say if someone purchases goods worth 245$ i want to add the 245 as reward points.. Can someone please let me know the best way to do this?

I noted that in opencart the reward points are saved in `oc_customer_reward` but i couldnt find the sql in the order model related to that.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking to add reward points into oc_customer_reward Table?

Comment: At present, the reward points assigned to the products are used when you order something. Are you looking to replace this?

Comment: `Edit product > Reward Points (TAB)`. Add the price of the product as points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could approach this - the easiest I can think of is in **system/library/cart/cart.php** (path depends on your version) change:

```
'reward'          => $reward * $cart['quantity'],
```

to

```
'reward'          => ($price + $option_price) * $cart['quantity'],
```

This way the rewards are passed to any other functions that rely on the cart data - including third party checkout extensions.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. I've used system/library/cart/cart.php to adjust for many things such as custom pricing and including the rewards in this manner

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following edit for automatic insertion of points when adding products.

admin/view/template/common/header.tpl
find:

```
</head>
```

add before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

      var product_reward = $("input[id=product_reward]");
        $("input[name^='price'],input[name='name'],input[name^='information_description'],input[name^='category_description']").keyup(function(){
          var autoPoints = $("input[name^='price'],input[name='name'],input[name^='information_description'],input[name^='category_description']").val();

          autoPoints = autoPoints * 0.05;

            product_reward.val(autoPoints);
        });
    });
      </script>
```

Comment: No point in adding yet another script when it can easily be accomplished directly in php via system/library/cart/cart.php as per @billynoah answer. It's the best way to do it.